# no me deja importar flask

Tags: python, python-3.x

necesito ayuda, cuando intento poner

```
from flask import Flask
```

me marca un error en el primer flask.

Comment: Normalmente es porque no iniciaste el entorno virtual, o algún error similar, como no  instalar la dependencia, en fin siempre te recomiendo poner el nombre del error y buscar el mismo por google antes de preguntar (si lo hiciste no hay drama suele pasar). Este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask) tiene varias respuestas que te pueden servir

Comment: a de ser que no lo tienes instalados intenta con `pip install flask` o `python -m pip install flask`

Comment: Yo lo soluciones, desinstalando Python y al instalarlo nuevamente marque la casilla: Add Python to PATH y ya me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que no tengas el modulo/paquete Flask.
Puedes verificar esto de muchas maneras y depende de tu entorno de trabajo

una forma simple es la siguiente en el mismo lugar que estas usando `from flask import Flask` comenta la línea y cualquier otro código, y coloca lo siguiente.

```py
import flask
print(flask.__version__)
```

si no tienes el modulo/paquete flask tendrás una respuesta como esta

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Ahora, es bueno que colocar más contexto en las preguntas, así puedes recibir una respuesta mas exacta. Para este caso sería muy útil saber qué ambiente de desarrollo estas utilizando y si estas utilizando ambientes virtuales como `pipenv`

---

## Anexo

Como lo menciona [Christian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183782/christian) en el comentario de abajo.

Otra manera de verificar que tienes instalado el modulo será usando `pip`.

Usa el terminal en tu ambiente de desarrollo (ejemplo, Pycharm en la parte inferior tendrá una ventana llamada terminal o consola) o usando CMD ( terminal/consola para Linux y MAC) navega a la carpeta de tu proyecto y usa el siguiente comando.

```
pip show flask
```

Si el modulo no está instalado tendrás el siguiente mensaje

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: flask
```

Comment: lo más simple es poner en la terminal `pip show flask` lo cual mostrará toda la información del módulo en caso esté instalado, de lo contrario un bonito mensaje diciendo que no lo tienes :)

Answer (score 0):

Existen varios posibles casos:

1. No has activado el entorno virtual de Python e instalaste Flask Allí

   source venv/bin/activate
   Suele servir.
2. No tienes Flask instalado. Utiliza Flask --version y debería aparecerte la versión en caso de que lo tengas. Si no aparecera algo así:

   zsh: command not found: flask

Saludos!